# Nginx does not show proxied server's pages

Tags: nginx

I have a service running on `localhost:5001` and i want to make it accessible from outside by default port. To that end i have added the following configuration file to `sites-avaiable` folder of nginx configuration folder:

```
server {
    listen 80;


    location / {
        if (-f /var/www-data/hq/downtime) {
            return 503;
        }
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    error_page 502 503 504 @maintenance;

    location @maintenance {
        # In this example, there's a directory in the site media files
        # called "downtime" that contains a "maintenance.html" file and
        # any styles and images needed for the maintenance page.
        root /var/www-data/hq/static/downtime;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;    
    }

}
```

However, all i get adter executing `nginx -s reload` is still defaulnt nginx welcome page.

What could be the reason for that behaviour? What should i change to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a symbolic link of your above config file in **sites-enabled** folder, so that nginx include this config file in it's config while loading all configuraton during starting/restarting.

Nginx only include config file which are available in **sites-enabled** folder.

You can do so by using this command

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconfigfile /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myconfigfile
```

Assume **myconfigfile** is your above given config file.

Then, restart nginx .

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that helped
I would ask you to add a reference to corresponding part of documentation